# Copy/Transfer files from local mac to local linux using python

Tags: linux, python-3.x, macos, nanopi

I am trying to automate copy/transfer a file from my local mac machine to a local nanopi-neo-linux machine. The two machine are connected via serial cable using VCP driver of Silicon Labs

`scp username@192.168.1.111:/path/to/myfile.txt /Users/Jamie/local/path/to/myfile.txt`

`scp` and `ssh` requires the host address/IP addres of the nanopi-neo-linux but I cannot get it without accessing it. I am accessing different nanopi-neo-linux machines so the IP address is dynamic.

Is there a way to directly copy/transfer a file without getting the IP address? or is it possible to directly extract the host address/IP address of nanopi-neo-linux so I can make it a variable?

Comment: I don't fully understand the last part of your question. Yes it is always necessary to know the IP address, weather it is dynamically or statically assigned.

Comment: I am looking for a way to get the IP of the nanopi-neo-linux machine from my mac machine.

Comment: Try `arp -a`. This gives the hosts in the local network.

Comment: But it gives all connected in the local network. Is there a way to get the specific IP address? My mac and linux are connected via serial cable (VCP driver of Silicon Labs)

Comment: I think you can use a Serial terminal to directly access the device, like `minicom` or `gtkterm`

Comment: are all ip addresses dynamic? and if you have serial connection and you don't want to connect to it every time, you can echo ip address of the target machine through the serial port. you can write some script that echoes the ip address to the serial port every few seconds?

Comment: @AmirH Yes, all IP addresses are dynamic. I think that would be very convenient if new devices through serial connection would be able to echo their IP.